# svn commit failed for no apparent reason

Tags: svn, commit

i have a repository at home that is checked out on my work computer for saving personal stuff like information i receive in emails etc while at work. yesterday i altered a file and went to commit it but i got an `svn: File not found` error. its very strange because i have not deleted any directories lately in this repository and everything is up to date. i am the only person who has access to the repo so i can't figure it out!

here is the sequence of commands:

```
$ svn update filename.pdf
At revision 551.
$ cp filename.pdf.new filename.pdf
$ svn ci filename.pdf -m "updated"
Sending        filename.pdf
Transmitting file data .svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: File not found: transaction '551-fg', path '/filesdir/filename.pdf'
```

if anyone has any ideas of how to solve this please let me know. i should also mention that the repository is stored on an external ntfs drive at home which i powerup and suspend remotely via ssh to make the drive live longer. it may be possible that the drive is dieing but there are no other signs of this.

all of the other posts i have seen with this error have been because someone deleted a directory and then did some kind of merge but i have not done anything like this - i just went to do a simple commit!

**edit upon Strelok's requests:**

```
$ pwd
..../filesdir
$ svn status
!       .
?       filename.pdf.new
M       filename.pdf
```

hmm so it looks like the `filesdir` directory is not found! that's very strange because i have definitely not deleted the directory! anyway, try updating the file only...

```
$ rm filename
$ cd ..
$ svn update filesdir
Restored 'filesdir/filename.pdf'
svn: Working copy path 'filesdir/filename.pdf' does not exist in repository
```

no luck. maybe try updating the whole directory that the faulty file is in...

```
$ mv filesdir/filename.pdf.new /tmp/
$ sudo rm -r filesdir/
$ svn update filesdir
A filesdir
A [lots of other files but not filename.pdf!!!]
$ cd filesdir
$ ls filename.pdf
ls: cannot access filename.pdf: No such file or directory
$ svn status filename.pdf
$ # no output!!!
$ mv /tmp/filename.pdf.new filename.pdf
$ svn status filename.pdf
?       filename.pdf
```

try adding the file to the repository since it seems to not be in the repository already!

```
$ svn add filename.pdf
A (bin)  filename.pdf
$ svn ci filename.pdf -m "added"
Adding  (bin)  filename.pdf
Transmitting file data .
Committed revision 552.
```

hmmmmm very strange... well its fixed (for now) but i have no idea what caused the screw up in the first place. ah well :P

Comment: I voted your question up for a novel way of sharing files between home and work :) I would have used Dropbox or whatever :)

Comment: @Strelok ah cheers. dropbox has been compromised before and anyway i don't like the idea of another company seeing my data

Comment: Check that the folder that this file is in is not deleted. That could be a problem.

Comment: And post your current `svn status` output

Comment: @Strelok ok i'm doing that now